# Confused with `bash -c` command - does not work with global variables

Tags: bash, while-loop, scripting, zsh

I have two shell commands, actually the same snippet, when pasted them in the terminal:

This works:

```sh
while true; do \
sleep 1; \
ping -c 1 'www.google.com'; echo $?; \
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then break; fi; \
done
```

this does not:

```sh
/bin/bash -c "(while true; do \
sleep 1; \
ping -c 1 'www.google.com'; \
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then break; fi; \
done); \
exit 0"
```

This second command tells me that the exit status is `130` (in the line where the if performs) even if ping performs well so it exit status should be 0.

It's like the commands inside the string that I pass to `/bin/bash -c` do not register the last exit value inside the global variable `$?`. Is there any way to achieve that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is this tagged zsh? Is this part of a zsh script?

Comment: I was launching this commands inside zsh, I thought that maybe the way in which zsh works differs with bash

Comment: When you run a script, it does not matter whether you run the script from zsh or python or whatever (unless of course when you **source** it). What could be more important is to add to your question **how** you invoked the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your double quoted string is being expanded BEFORE the commands in the string are being interpreted by `bash -c` so that `$?` is likely a previous command's exit code.

You can see this with an example where we also use the `-x` flag to see what's happening under the hood:

```
$ set -x
$ bash -c "v=5; echo $v"
+ bash -c 'v=3; echo '
```

You can see that there is no value of `$v` to echo when execution hits that line as `$v` was already replaced before the command was interpreted by `bash -c`.

For further expirementation; to get nearly the same output as your issue, do the following:

1. Run `cat` with no parameters and ctrl+c to interupt.
2. Run `bash -c "echo 'hi'; echo $?"`

You should get `hi` and `130` as the output, which was the exit code of your sigint'd `cat` command. (*note that it's not the exit `0` of the `echo "hi"` as you might expect*).

---

Thankfully for your command, you can just swap out your quotes to avoid this issue:

```
/bin/bash -c '(while true; do \
sleep 1; \
ping -c 1 "www.google.com"; \
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then break; fi; \
done); \
exit 0'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, also for the explanation! It was a subtle error indeed, for a moment I thought about the " / ' difference but I thought it expanded only the variables (and wrongfully do not consider that `$?` is indeed a variable!)